# How can I extract 1st element of owl carousel content?

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I am creating a slider which have 2 section top and bottom. I want to show the content of bottom slider on the top slider. How can I Achieve this? I have tried to add class on the 1st element of item. but it didn't work. please someone who know how to target 1st elemt of owl-carousel answer please.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Owl Carausel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<body>

<style>
    .item{
        height: 40vh;
        background-color: rgb(211, 38, 38);
        color: #fff;
    }
    .hero{
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: aqua;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><h4>14444</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
 
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({

    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    },
})


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the result (try it yourself) you can tell that `owl-item` is the class of each slide. So if you want the 5th slide do

```
.owl-item:nth-child(5)
```

This is not a recommended way because it's hacking into the implementation of the slider. Although in this case I assume it's part of their API so you can count on `owl-item` to stay the same.